# Failing to get unobtrusive client validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor, unobtrusive

I figured out that property i want to be validated has to have [Required] attribute in C#
(am i right?)
If so -my model is linq generated class - how to add this attribute?

Comment: Take a look at a tool like Automapper.  You can automatically map your domain model to a viewmodel which you can then perform validation on.  You don't typically ever want to present a domain model to a user.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways:

- If it's possible, make the field non-nullable in the database.  This will make the field required at the data layer.
- Create a partial class that adds a property to your model class.  Use this property instead of the database-generated property.

For example:

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
   [Required]
   public string YourNewProperty
   {
      get { return this.TheRealProperty; }
      set { this.TheRealProperty = value; }
   }
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

well, you could always make a new class, as a part of a Data access layer, with the same attributes, just put [required] where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your LINQ classes are partials. With MVC, you can use the "[MetatDataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx)"

Like so

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadataSource))]
public partial class User {

}

class UserMetadataSource {
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

}
```